# Is it possible to express and prove a theorem only with commutative diagrams?

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra

By saying "only", I mean that no words are involved except "commutative". Just draw a commutative diagram, and make some arrows dotted lines to mean "the other arrows already exist, and this is what the theorem demonstrates to exist".

To prove a theorem like this, we first draw all the conditions as solid arrows, and try to prove that a new arrow exists. We can use other theorems in this style by stacking them up to show the existence of other arrows in the diagram. Then we might get to the arrow we want, everything like doing a high school geometry problem.

However, It seems difficult to rewrite the theorems in linear algebra or abstract algebra, because it involves too many statements that are not shown in the commutative diagram, like injectivity, or the kernel being connected in another kernel, or some maps being "canonical". For example,

Suppose $\varphi:E\to F$ and $\psi: E\to G$ are linear mappings such that $\ker\varphi\subset\ker \psi$, then exists $\chi:F\to G$ such that $\chi\circ\varphi = \psi$.

The last statement can certainly be a commutative diagram (I can't draw it here), and $\chi$ is a dotted line. but where is the crucial $\ker\varphi\subset\ker \psi$ condition? Therefore, I can't figure it out.

Is there some ways that make this idea possible?

Comment: Title: Depends on the theorem. How would you do it for $2^p\equiv 2\bmod p$ for odd primes $p$?

Comment: Well, you would need to say words either on paper or in your head to justify *why* the diagram, or subdiagrams of it, commute, and also to justify existence of the dotted fill-ins. I've written plenty of proofs by literally just drawing an elaborate diagram but that's by omitting plenty of (obvious) necessary remarks

Comment: Dietrich Burde I think it's enough just rewriting the fundamental ones about homomorphisms.

Comment: Are we allowed to decorate arrows, for example use $\rightarrowtail$ or $\twoheadrightarrow$?

Comment: John Palmieri I think yes, as long as we can prove theorems by glueing the decorated diagrams together.